# Using Swagger with scala-activerecord

Tags: scala, activerecord, swagger, fieldinfo

I have an active record like this:

```
case class Person(name: String) extends ActiveRecord
object Person extends ActiveRecordCompanion[Person]
```

I added Swagger annotations:

```
@ApiModel(value = "Person", description = "A person.")
case class Person(
                 @ApiModelProperty(value = "A person's name")
                   name: String) extends ActiveRecord
object Person extends ActiveRecordCompanion[Person]
```

The generated schema contains a lot of junk rendering it unusable:

```
"Person": {
      "id": "Person",
      "description": "A person.",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "valid": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "errors": {
          "$ref": "Errors"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int64"
        },
        "persisted": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "_companion": {
          "$ref": "com.github.aselab.activerecord.inner.ProductModelCompanion<com.github.aselab.activerecord.inner.ProductModel>"
        },
        "_isNewRecord": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "newRecord": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "com$github$aselab$activerecord$ActiveRecordBase$$_isDeleted": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "recordCompanion": {
          "$ref": "com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecordBaseCompanion<java.lang.Object, com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecordBase>"
        },
        "com$github$aselab$activerecord$validations$Validatable$$_validated": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "deleted": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
```

I looked into the source code of `swagger-core`. There is a `ModelPropertyParser` with a method `parseRecursive` that contains:

```
for (field <- hostClass.getDeclaredFields) {
        if (Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) && !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && !ignoredProperties.contains(field.getName) && !field.isSynthetic()) {
          if (ignoredProperties.contains(field.getName)) {
            LOGGER.debug("ignoring property " + field.getName)
          } else {
            parseField(field)
          }
        }
      }

      Option(hostClass.getSuperclass).map(parseRecursive(_))
```

When I run:

```
> classOf[Person].getDeclaredFields
Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array(private final java.lang.String sk.essentialdata.ress.search.db.Person.name)
```

It is correct, because I have declared just one field.

When I run:

```
classOf[Person].getSuperclass.getDeclaredFields
res6: Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array(private final long com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecord.id, private boolean com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecord.com$github$aselab$activerecord$ActiveRecordBase$$_isDeleted, private final com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecordBaseCompanion com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecord.recordCompanion, private final com.github.aselab.activerecord.validations.Errors com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecord.errors, private boolean com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecord.com$github$aselab$activerecord$validations$Validatable$$_validated, private final com.github.aselab.activerecord.inner.ProductModelCompanion com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecord._companion, private boolean com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecord...
```

There is a lot of internal fields of ActiveRecord. Is there a way to get rid of this junk? I only need to include the fields from `fieldInfo` in the swagger description:

```
> Person.fieldInfo
scala> res0: Map[String,com.github.aselab.activerecord.reflections.FieldInfo] = Map(name -> FieldInfo(name,class java.lang.String,false,false,WrappedArray()), id -> FieldInfo(id,long,false,false,WrappedArray()))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/develop_scala-2.10/modules/swagger-core/src/main/scala/com/wordnik/swagger/converter/ModelConverters.scala#L176) you'll see some special handling for `ebean` subclasses.  You can easily add the same for `ActiveRecordCompanion` as follows:

- Extend `ModelConverter` and override the `propertyPackagesToSkip` with the package you want to skip
- Add your new ModelConverter to the converter chain with this:

  ModelConverters.addConverter(yourConverter, true) // puts it first in the chain

You should see the model processing avoid traversing the class you are skipping.